# Rename folder which contains special characters using PHP

Tags: php, html, utf-8

I have the following names in my database and also in directories.

```
Zúñnga
Mariè
etc...
```

The problem is I tried to do this:

```
$oldname = '/home/website/public_html/profile/Zúñnga';
$newname = '/home/website/public_html/profile/Zuunga';

rename($oldname, $newname)
```

And it doesn't work...

The names are stored in a database.

This is the following script I've been using to get the names out of the database, convert them to UTF-8, but simply the rename function doesn't work...

```
...
foreach($query as $item)
{
    $name_tags = utf8_encode($item['name_tags']);

    $oldname = '/home/website/public_html/profile/'.$name_tags.'';

    $text = iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT', $name_tags);
    $text_1 = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $text);
    $text_2 =  preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9- ]/", '', $text_1);
    $name_tags_updated =  str_replace(" ", "-", $text_2);


        $newname = '/home/website/public_html/profile/'.$name_tags_updated.'';
        rename($oldname, $newname)

        $sql = 'UPDATE posts SET name_tags = "'.$name_tags_updated.'" where id = "'.$item['id'].'";
        ...
}
```

The query part is working fine; it's replacing the name with the good letters in the database, but when it comes to renaming the directory it simply doesn't work. Instead of changing the name to it's actual file, it just doesn't. I've tried to verify it this way

```
if(rename($oldname, $newname))
        echo 'success';
    else
        echo 'fail';
```

it returns fail

On my website sometimes they are returned like this:

```
Mari�
```

Comment: You shouldn't write SQL like that and shouldn't store user input like that. If you list the contents on the system are the characters the same? I found mac and linux differed on their storage systems with accented characters. So a `é` from mac keyboard didn't match `é` on linux system. Linux used the single code point where as mac used the dual code point. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494883/utf8-character-makes-file-inaccessible maybe using wildcard could work

Comment: First you need to know what character set your filesystem is using, because otherwise we're just speculating. Use something like `glob()` to list the directory contents, and `bin2hex()` to turn it into a representation that you can safely copy/paste to SO. Knowing your OS and filesystem type would also be useful.

Comment: Additionally, `utf8_encode()` and `utf8_decode()` are awful functions that should be avoided. They will only ever convert between UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1, will happily corrupt your data if used incorrectly, and [are virutally _never_ used correctly](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_utf8_decode_and_utf8_encode#usage).

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"it doesn't work"*? What happens (or doesn't happen)? What are the symptoms? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74647190/edit), not here in comments (*************** ***without*** *************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).